# MFC CListbox GetItemData failed

Tags: c++, sorting, mfc, listbox

I used `DrawItem()` to redraw my `CListbox`. For some reasons, I want to use custom compare to sort my list item with my own rules, and I use `LBS_SORT` and no `LBS_HASSTRING` properties. After using `SetItemData()` in `OnInitDialog()`, I get these data in `DrawItem()`, but it didn't work. Code is like below:

**init code** :

```
void OnInitDialog(...) 
{
    .........
    m_List.SetListHeight (40);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++) {
        m_List.AddString ((const char *) i);
        m_List.SetItemData (i,(100 + i));
    }
    ....
}
```

**compare code** :

```
int CompareItem(LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT lpCompareItemStruct) 
{       
    ASSERT(lpCompareItemStruct->CtlType == ODT_LISTBOX);

    int     a = lpCompareItemStruct->itemData1;
    int     b = lpCompareItemStruct->itemData2;

    return (a - b);
}
```

**redraw code :**

```
DrawItem (lpDIS) 
{
        ..................
        CString     str;

        int         i = (int) GetItemData (lpDIS->itemID); // the i is not what I expect. 

        str.Format ("%d", (int) i);

        dc.DrawText (str,CRect (&lpDIS->rcItem), DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE); 
        ...................
}
```

**when I use**

```
        ***index = m_List.addstring ((const char *) i) ;
        m_List.setitemdata (index,(100 + i));***
```

**it works ,but if I use a struct to addstring ,the index is not right ,code is like this below :**

```
struct      test {
    int     a,b,c,d;
};

init_code :

            test        *ptest = new test[20];      /* just a test ,we don't delete memory till application ends */

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++) {
        ptest [i].a = i;
        int index = m_List.AddString ((const char *) (ptest + i));
        m_List.SetItemDataPtr (index,(void *) (100 + i));
    }

compare code :

int ListEx::CompareItem(LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT lpCompareItemStruct) 
{
    // TODO: Add your code to determine the sorting order of the specified items
    // return -1 = item 1 sorts before item 2
    // return 0 = item 1 and item 2 sort the same
    // return 1 = item 1 sorts after item 2

//  ASSERT(lpCompareItemStruct->CtlType == ODT_LISTBOX);

    test *pa,*pb;

    pa = (test *) lpCompareItemStruct->itemData1;  // crashed here 
    pb = (test *) lpCompareItemStruct->itemData2;

//  ASSERT (pa);
//  ASSERT (pb);

    return (pa->a - pb->a);
}

draw_item code :

        CString     str;

        test  *ptest = (test *) (lpDIS->itemData);

        str.Format ("%d", (int) ptest->a);

        dc.DrawText (str,CRect (&lpDIS->rcItem), DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
```

**Is addstring can only use strings ??? 
if the item is a struct data ,how could I set these struct data to the listbox item ???**

Comment: it means the i we getitemdata () is not what i want .

Answer (score 0):

In OnInitDialog you should do this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++) {
   int index = m_List.AddString ((const char *) i);
   m_List.SetItemData (index, 100 + i);
}
```

`AddString` returns the index where the item has been inserted (which can be anywhere if the list is sorted). `m_List.SetItemData (index ,(100 + i))` sets the data for the item you just have inserted.

Comment: thanks a lot ,another problem ,when I use addstring ((const char *) i),it works ,but if I use  a struct to addstring ,it won't work ...

Comment: @true_casey: Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: The list could loose data, because if there is an underlying relocation, item data aren't copied. I've seen this behavior on a Windows 8.1 platform, and to solve it I just made two consecutive loops...

Answer (score 0):

we can set structure data to list box.

```
struct _empInfo {
    CString strName;
    ..............
} empInfo = {L"XYZ",...};

m_list.AddString(empinfo.strName);
```

I tried above code in my app..

Comment: I guess i have solved it...   LBS_SORT and no LBS_HASSTRING means the  SetItemData ,SetItemDataPtr AddString are the same thing ,so you can use just use only one of them ....

LBS_SORT and LBS_HASSTRING means the inner CListBox will alloc an extral memory to store the string ..

that's the difference between them I guess

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I did a test ,code is like this 
 `for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++) {`
  `int index = m_List.AddString ((const char *) (i));`
  `m_List.SetItemDataPtr (index,(void *) (10000 + i));`
 `}`

int draw_item () ,:
  `CString  str;`
  `int a = (int) GetItemDataPtr (index);`
  `int b = (int) lpDIS->itemData;`

  `str.Format ("a = %d,b = %d", (int) a,(int) b);`

 lpDIS->itemData and getitemdata  are the same value ...

**it turned out that I'm right ....**